# A book about an asian character (either japanese or korean) who almost gets hit by a car but gets teleported to this video game like reality

Tags: story-identification, books

I remember this book I read a long while ago and my library didn't have the second book so I dropped it. I think it was called "Push" or "Pull" but when I search it up the right book never shows up. I don't know the name of the author.

All I know is that the girl tries to save a deaf girl from getting ran over but she gets in the way of the car, she gets "saved" by a boy and teleports to this video-game like reality. We get introduced to other teenagers and one girl dies at one point but they can't do anything cuz her wristband is like all the way to red. The main character falls in love with the leader of the group (which i'm hoping doesn't result in a stupid love triangle with the other dude) and well he dies after attempting to save her? i think?

Later, the MC believes that the leader guy is still alive and **now I can't find the second book.**

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Approximately when did you read this?  Do you recall the cover art?

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/20774) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: Is this a comic book? A book with largely text? A picture book?

Comment: If someone posts the correct answer, you can accept by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This may be Eve Silver's *[The Game](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B074CC5CL4)* series. From the blurb for *[Rush](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B009NF6B8I)*, the first book:

[image: Front cover of Rush]

> Rush pulls you headlong into the thrilling, high-stakes world of Eve Silver's teen series The Game, about teens pulled into and out of an alternate reality in which battling aliens is more than a game--it's life and death. This teen debut novel offers science fiction and gaming fans romantic thrills at a breakneck pace.
>
> Seventeen-year-old Miki Jones's carefully controlled life spirals into chaos after she's run down in the street, left broken and bloody. She wakes up fully healed in a place called the lobby--pulled from her life, pulled through time and space into some kind of game in which she and a team of other teens are sent on missions to eliminate the Drau, terrifying and beautiful alien creatures.
>
> There are no practice runs, no training, and no way out. Miki has only the guidance of secretive but maddeningly attractive team leader Jackson Tate, who says that the game is more than that, and that what Miki and her new teammates do now determines their survival and the survival of every other person on this planet. She laughs. He doesn't. And then the game takes a deadly and terrifying turn.

I can't bring up the link from where I'm posting, but indeed, Miki gets run down while trying to save a deaf girl from an oncoming truck.

The second book is titled *[Push](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00FJ32Y5C)*.

Found by searching ISFDB.org for books titled Push and then plugging the title and author into Google for the novel entries.